# How to generate a clean sql script using visual studio database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have created an `SQL Server Database Project` using `Visual Studio 2013`. The build and `Publish` work fine (all changes from project are executed on database) but when I choose 'Generate Script' (instead of `Publish`) an `.sql` file is generated but it cannot be run directly (without modifying it) in `SQL Server Management Studio` because some of the following lines are not part of `SQL` language (those which starts with ":"):

```
GO
:setvar DatabaseName "Test_Project"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "Test_Project"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "<default path>"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "<default log path>"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];
```

How can generate a "clean" `SQL` file when I press `Generate Script` button? If it is not possible how can I transform the result into a `SQL` file which can be interpreted by `SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: Just enable SQLCMD mode in SSMS (Query menu -> SQLCMD Mode) and the query will run fine. SSMS can also be configured to automatically enable SQLCMD mode in Tools menu -> Options -> Query Execution.

Comment: Thanks "@GarethLyons"! it worked. Do you have any idea if Is there a tool to convert SQLCMD code to SQL code?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pass the sqlcmd script into sqlcmd.exe with parameters. There's an example of this in [this Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssehgal/2009/04/03/passing-parameters-to-sql-script-using-batch-files/).

As far as I'm aware there's no way of outputting the sql file with the supplied parameters substituted in.